# Add DIV with Append, but no CSS style

Tags: jquery, css, html, append

I have a problem with a jQuery script. I added a new DIV into a other DIV with the function append, but the CSS style doesn't pick the declared DIV class.

For example:

```
<style">
  .example { background-color:#00000; }
</style>

$('#test).append('<div class="example"></div>');
```

I loaded the stylesheet with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/example.css">
```

Comment: Your example, missing quote and zero aside, should work. CSS does not accept five-digit colour codes.

Comment: try out firebug http://getfirebug.com/ to debug all this issues.

Comment: your color code is incorrect as pointed out by Amadan

Comment: Check if the stylesheet is loaded properly. Open your developer toolbar and follow the stylesheet's link to see if its grabbing the right file (or if that file even exists).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following :

```
$('#test').append($('<div></div>').attr('class', 'example'));
```

Or

```
$('#test').html('<div class="example"></div>');
```